# What's the origin of "hung for a toad"? Where is it used?

Tags: phrases, phrase-origin

The phrase I have heard most often from my father usually went like this:

> Well I'll be hung for a toad!

Where did this saying come from and has anyone else heard it?  My dad's dad & mother were respectively Scots & Irish if that helps. 
He would exclaim that saying when something was a surprise.

It's not mentioned in online dictionaries such as [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hung%20for%20a%20toad).

Comment: In order to try to prevent this question from being closed as "requires research", I'm adding a reference to a dictionary. I also made some (hopefully minor) changes to the title to make it clearer. However, given that I cannot find the expression anywhere on the internet, I doubt that you'll get any answer.

Comment: Possibly a mutation of [*"I might as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+might+as+well+be+hanged+for+a+sheep+as+a+lamb)?

Comment: My father occasionally said, as an expression of surprise "I'll go to Putney on a pig!" Another expression quite well known in the East Midlands of England is "I'll go to the foot of our stairs!" Perhaps they are all euphemisms for "I'll be damned!"

Answer (score 1):

*meta:* Look up the word *toad* in a good dictionary, not the phrase.
*"Hung for a toad" is not a set phrase or idiom.

> A ***toad*** is a [**2** A] contemptible or detestable person (used as a general term of abuse)

"Well I'll be hung for a toad!"

should likely mean that one will get severely punished for behaving in a contemptible or detestable manner.